# Why doesn't Twitter use their own Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter, twitter-bootstrap

I took a look at the Twitter CSS and it's completely diferent from the Twitter Bootstrap CSS. It doesn't use Bootstrap's grid system, and it isn't responsive.

Do they have anything in common other than the developers?

Comment: well, the nav bar is the same :s

Comment: I'm not sure if anyone here could definitively answer the question "Why doesn't Twitter user their own Bootstrap?". I'm voting to close as non-constructive. StackOverflow is for practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face.

Comment: no, they aren't. Just as google.com doesn't use Angular nor Material and Bill Gates uses android.

Comment: @ET-CS Google does use Material. If you class Material as "tons of shadows everywhere with rounded corners exactly 5px", then you're referring to bad use of Material.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

[My answer at Quora](http://www.quora.com/Twitter-Bootstrap/Does-Twitter-use-Twitter-Bootstrap/):

> Internally, we use it in a lot of applications. On [Twitter.com](http://twitter.com), you
>   can find bits and pieces in our dropdown menus, forms, and buttons.

Comment: Straight from the horses mouth :P ..good job sir on an awesome project. Salute from the Dominican Republic.

Comment: Thanks for the attention, and welcome to stackoverflow. Lots of people with questions about twitter-bootstrap over here.

Comment: it's a really heavy framework for twitter.  They use it on internal applications because, with lower volumes there's less overhead to serving that package.

Answer (score 4):

I think bootstrap is just a side project of two developers that work for Twitter. It doesn't necessarily have anything to do with twitter itself.

Comment: It's advertised as "Bootstrap, from Twitter", and it's a repo on their github page.

Comment: Yeah I understand, but I mean it's from twitter as in, it's from the developers of Twitter. That doesn't necessarily mean that Twitter uses it.